# Employee Directory Issues

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, people-search, mysite

I am trying to build an employee directory in SP 2013 on premise and I found this article"
 http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2013/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-people-directory/

but the problem is that when I query spspeople, I get no result, I have imported user profiles from AD, my UPSS is up and running, mysite host is configured yet I cant get results when I search for people. Is there anyone who have had experience with this?

Comment: did you configure the Search services application and also run the full crawl on people search.

Comment: Yes I did, I can send mails, share site but cant find people on search.

Comment: this is what i am asking...http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582311(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up a Content Source for People? Usually this involves creating a Content Source in the Search Service Application that uses the following URL: sps3://mysitehost, where mysitehost is the URL of the My Site Host site collection.